# Ideas for handling images with webpack

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

This is my current project setup:

```
dist/
├── bundle.js
└── index.html
src/
├── main.js
├── img/
│    └── icon.svg
├── js/
└── styles/
     └── page.css
webpack.config.js
```

When I want to reference an image inside of my `index.html` file

```
<img src="img/icon.svg">
```

I first need to require it inside my `main.js` file in order to get processed and build inside this `dist/img/` directory, when I now want to use the icon in my css as well I get referencing issues. Hope you could give me some advice on how to optimize my setup.

```
const path = require('path');

const excludeDirectorys = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: 'dist/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // => JS Loader
      { test: /\.js$/,include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), exclude: excludeDirectorys, loader: 'babel-loader', query: { presets: ['es2015']} },
      // => CSS Loader
      { test: /\.css$/, exclude: excludeDirectorys, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'autoprefixer-loader'] },
      // => SASS Loader
      { test: /\.(sass|scss)$/, exclude: excludeDirectorys, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'autoprefixer-loader', 'sass-loader'] },
      // => Image Loader
      { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, exclude: excludeDirectorys, loaders: ['file-loader?name=./img/[name].[ext]', 'image-webpack?'] }
    ]
  },
};
```

Comment: Can you provide the error please?

Comment: I either get an error inside the browser, that the request image url can't be found or when I change the url inside my styles file webpack can't compile my code.

Comment: You should look at the img tag src attribute in your build and probably you will see what is wrong with the reference to your image file. I can guess the problem is the file loader name option. Try `name=img/[name].[ext]` without `./` in your file-loader config.

Comment: It would be nice to get the compilation error so we know which loader failed, like the URLs getting provided to `css-loader` might be wrong, etc. Usually, there's enough information in there for such obvious issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a top level static HTML file, I would use the html-webpack-plugin, which will let you do things like:

```
<img src="<%= require('../path/to/icon.svg') %>" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, but I may need to change my question a little bit because this method doesn't seem like the real deal to me. How would you handle images inside of your project?

Comment: "How would you handle images inside of your project?" is too vague to answer - can you be more specific? Ideally by editing the question.